# My website on checking showing 403 error on HTTP Status

Tags: redirect

My website is running fine but when I check on the https://httpstatus.io/, it is showing the 403 error and also on the Google page insights, it is not showing the report.

My website DNS is currently pointing to the Cloudflare and previously I have installed the Cloudflare plugin in my Wordpress and now I have uninstalled it.

If I removed my website from Cloudflare, the problem will be solved or not, Or it will affect my website.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: 403 status code means access is forbidden, note that this isn't a Cloudflare support forum though, it's a WP development Q&A site, you'll need to contact your host or Cloudflare support

Comment: @TomJNowell, I think its a WordPress question because it is connected to hosting.